# use and purpose of websocket multiplexing extension

Tags: html, websocket

I am trying to understand the purpose of websocket multiplexing extension, the main purpose what the document states is to use a single same origin physical websocket connection to the server while each browser tab uses a logical connection multiplexed on top of physical connection. I see another alternative using which we can accomplish this behavior today, the approach is to launch a shared web worker which opens the websocket connection and let each browser tab send and receive message to/from this worker. i have not tried this yet and i wonder will this work at all.

Answer (score 14):

Your question reflects a misunderstanding of the problem the WebSocket Multiplexing Extension is trying to solve.

The *base* WebSocket spec (RFC 6455) defines a protocol for bi-directional exchange of data over TCP/IP.  A WebSocket starts as a normal HTTP request / response. In this exchange, the client and server negotiate to switch to the WebSocket protocol.  After the switch, the client and server exchange data frames over the TCP/IP connection.  This creates a bi-directional data stream between client and server.

A drawback of the base protocol is that it supports only a single stream of data flowing in each direction.  The *multiplexing extension* augments the base protocol, by allowing the client and server to create multiple "channels" over the same TCP/IP connection.

**So the purpose of the multiplexing extension is to allow multiple WebSocket channels to run over the same TCP/IP connection.** That's all.

Having multiple browser tabs (or web workers) share a single TCP/IP connection is just an *example* of how multiplexed websockets *might* be used. In standards terminology, it's just "informative" (descriptive), not "normative" (a required part of the spec).